# Visual Studio UWP: Where is the path to External Dependencies defined?

Tags: visual-studio, uwp

I have a UWP C++ project with links to external Dependencies, that have `#includes`  to files that don't exist.

eg

[image]

This is actually the Cordova SQLite windows plugin, so not a project I created myself.

When I build, I get many errors...

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "wrl\client.h"  SQLite3.UWP C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\agile.h  16  
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "winapifamily.h"    SQLite3.UWP C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.15063.0\ucrt\corecrt.h  196 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "IUnknown" is undefined  SQLite3.UWP C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\agile.h  26  
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "HRESULT" is undefined   SQLite3.UWP C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\agile.h  27  
Error (active)  E0145   variable "Platform::Details::GetProxyImpl" may not be initialized   SQLite3.UWP C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\agile.h  27  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "IUnknown"  SQLite3.UWP C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\agile.h  27  
Error (active)  E0029   expected an expression  SQLite3.UWP C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\agile.h  27  
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "HRESULT" is undefined   SQLite3.UWP C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\agile.h  28  
Error (active)  E0145   variable "Platform::Details::ReleaseInContextImpl" may not be initialized   SQLite3.UWP C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\agile.h  28  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "IUnknown"  SQLite3.UWP C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\agile.h  28  
Error (active)  E0029   expected an expression  SQLite3.UWP C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\agile.h  28  
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "HRESULT" is undefined   SQLite3.UWP C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\agile.h  31  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "IUnknown"  SQLite3.UWP C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\agile.h  31  
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "HRESULT" is undefined   SQLite3.UWP C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\agile.h  37  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "IUnknown"  SQLite3.UWP C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\agile.h  37  
Error (active)  E0059   function call is not allowed in a constant expression   SQLite3.UWP C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.15063.0\ucrt\corecrt.h  197 
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'winapifamily.h': No such file or directory   SQLite3.UWP c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\ucrt\corecrt.h  196
```

When I browse to where one of the files that does exist reside, explorer open up at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.15063.0\ucrt`. This files has (for example) the following  `#include <winapifamily.h>`, and this file does not exist in that folder.

However, if I search for this file in the root of the Window Kit folder, I do find it in other folders..

[image]

Going into the project properties, I see the following...

[image]

Finally drilling in more, I see...

[image]

So, the version it appears to be referencing is 10.0.15063.0, and this folder does **NOT** have some of the headers being referenced.

My question is, today (Sept 2019), on Windows 10, how do I defined this (and other ) include paths?

I have read many posts, but depending on the post date, you get different answers and none have helped in my case.

### Update 1

Going into the project settings, I noticed that the Platform Toolset was set to v140.

I swapped this to v141 as below...

[image]

I now get less errors...

[image]

And the source folder for one of the files referencing the missing `winapifamily.h` is now `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.15063.0\ucrt`

Opening it, I can see that the `winapifamily.h` is still not there.
Where would there be a a collection of headers in such a toolkit that references missing files... I just can't understand this.

### Update 2

I have removed and readded the plugin, and went from `3.2.0` to `^3.3.0"`

The file referencing the `winapifamily.h` (corecrt.h) is located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.15063.0\ucrt`, and there is no `winapifamily.h` in this folder.

Platform toolkit in the UWP project is set to `Visual Studio 2017 (v141)`

Answer (score 0):

I realised I did not have Windows 10 SDK (10.0.15063.0) installed. I went into Visual Studio installer and went into modify for Visual Studio 2017

After installing these (for desktop, UWP and C++), my project would finally build.